# Expression is always true in C#

Tags: c#, .net

A simple C# code

```
    bool result;
    if (bool.TryParse("false", out result) && result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

and

```
    bool result;
    if (bool.TryParse("tRue", out result) && result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Resharper says that result in `Console.WriteLine(result)` is always `true`. Why?

Comment: Note it doesn't say `result` is always true -- it says `result` __in Console.WriteLine(result)__ is always true

Comment: You don't need `&& result`.  Just remove it from your condition.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, you are wrong. I want to show console only if result  is true

Comment: Then Resharper is correctly stating your intent, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand, how has this question been upvoted? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's due to the `&& result` part - you'll only ever get into the body of the statement if `result` is true. How do you anticipate any way of getting in there with `result` being `false`?

Comment: Being constantly rep-capped must be a real bummer. :)

Answer (score 4):

What Reharper is telling you is that, if you are doing

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

you might as well do

```
Console.WriteLine(true);
```

That is, anywhere you use result within the if, you can as well use true, as, if `result` were false, the you would not have reached the body of the if.

Comment: Meaningless statement is meaningless, in other words.

Answer (score 2):

Because `if(true && false)` (thats what you get, when you resolve the parsing) will never enter the if body. Thats what you are parsing in the first example.